# Java unmarshaller exception

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I am using JAXB parser to convert a XML file to Java objects and I am getting the exception:

Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"charges"). Expected elements are <{}service>,<{}servicemethod>,<{}userclass>

I've already included the annotation @XmlRootElement to the class but it didn't help.

XML File

```
<charges>
<userclass>
    <classname>adhoc</classname>
    <service>
        <serviceclass>local</serviceclass>
        <servicemethod charge="0.05">call</servicemethod>
        <servicemethod charge="0.02">text</servicemethod>
    </service>
</userclass>
<userclass>
    <classname>prepaid</classname>
    <service>
        <serviceclass>longdistance</serviceclass>
        <servicemethod charge="0.05">call</servicemethod>
        <servicemethod charge="0.02">text</servicemethod>
    </service>
    <service>
        <serviceclass>international</serviceclass>
        <servicemethod charge="0.25">call</servicemethod>
        <servicemethod charge="0.10">text</servicemethod>
    </service>
    <service>
        <serviceclass>local</serviceclass>
        <servicemethod charge="0.01">call</servicemethod>
        <servicemethod charge="0.01">text</servicemethod>
    </service>
</userclass>
<userclass>
    <classname>monthly</classname>
    <service>
        <serviceclass>longdistance</serviceclass>
        <servicemethod charge="0.03">call</servicemethod>
        <servicemethod>text</servicemethod>
    </service>
    <service>
        <serviceclass>international</serviceclass>
        <servicemethod charge="0.05">call</servicemethod>
        <servicemethod>text</servicemethod>
    </service>
    <service>
        <serviceclass>local</serviceclass>
        <servicemethod>call</servicemethod>
        <servicemethod>text</servicemethod>
    </service>
</userclass>
</charges>
```

Charges class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;


@XmlAccessorType (XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {"userclass"}, factoryClass=ObjectFactory.class,    factoryMethod="createChargers")
@XmlRootElement(name="charges", namespace="")
public class Charges {
    List<Userclass> userclass;

    public List<Userclass> getUserClasses() {
        if (userclass == null) {
            userclass = new ArrayList<Userclass>();
        }
        return this.userclass;
    }
}
```

If anyone could tell me where I'm going wrong, it'd be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have forgotten to included the `Charges` in the classes used to bootstrap the `JAXBContext`.  Try marshalling an instance of `Charges` to see what happens.

Comment: I've tried marshalling an instance of Charges but I get the same exception.

Comment: @alereis - If the `marshal` fails you should get a `MarshalException`.